# Connecting flight in Tel Aviv

Tags: transit, connecting-flights, israel, tel-aviv, el-al

I am flying from Cyprus to Dubai with a 2.5 hour layover in Tel Aviv airport. Am I allowed to do this with the COVID restrictions? I am fully vaccinated and will have a negative PCR test less than 72 hours old. My friend said no connections are allowed in Tel Aviv?

EDIT  I only have hand luggage and the flights are with Ryan air and El Al

Comment: At the very least you'll have to tell us whether the two flights are on a single ticket and whether you have checked luggage.

Comment: I only have hand luggage and the flights are with Ryan air and El Al

Comment: This means you are self-connecting, so for Ryanair your final destination is Tel Aviv. Also, even if you check-in online, you need to get to the check-in counter for your second flight at the latest 1 hour before departure. Do you meet all current requirements to enter Israel? Also note that a self-connection is at your own risk. If you miss your second flight, you'll be considered a no show, and your ticket will most likely be cancelled, including all subsequent flights on the ticket, and you'll need to book and pay for a new flight at last minute prices (+ hotel, meals...).

Comment: Also, what's your citizenship, and did you stay in any other countries than Cyprus recently?

Comment: Not very familiar with current rules for Israel, but Timatic says no entry or transit is allowed unless you have an "authorization letter issued by the Population and Immigration Authority" or an A1 or A5 visa issues by Israel. Also, as you would not qualify for TWOV, a visa would be required for transit.

Comment: When are you travelling? Rules change all the time, of course.

Comment: October 27th, apparently British citizens visiting for less than 3 months (me) are exempt from visa requirements so that's some good news https://mfa.gov.il/MFA/ConsularServices/Documents/VisaRequirements-Tourists.pdf

Comment: Note that the visa requirement discussed on that page is strictly only for immigration purposes. It does not include COVID-related restrictions. It's very difficult to guess what the rules will bee by October 27th. The current plan is to relax restrictions a little, but predictions have turned out very wrong a large number of times since the beginning of the pandemic.

Comment: Interested to hear if you managed to travel.

Answer (score 4):

[Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/fr/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=gb&destination=ae&transit=il) (the database used by airlines to determine eligibility and required documentation -- note that I randomly picked UK citizenship, you may want to "change search" to get results for your actual citizenship) **currently** states:

> #### Admission and Transit Restrictions:
>
> **Passengers are not allowed to enter and transit.**
>
> Information: This does not apply to passengers with an authorization letter issued by the Population and Immigration Authority.
>
> Information: This does not apply to passengers with an A1 or A5 visa issued by Israel.
>
> Information: This does not apply to passengers with an A2, A3, A4, B1, B3 or B4 visa issued by Israel, if they are not arriving from Argentina, Belarus, Brazil, Cyprus, Georgia, India, Kyrgyzstan, Mexico, Russian Fed., South Africa, Spain, Turkey, United Kingdom or Uzbekistan.

(emphasis mine)

Since you're arriving from Cyprus, the last case does not apply to you, so the only way you could enter or transit would be to have "an [authorization letter issued by the Population and Immigration Authority](https://www.gov.il/en/departments/news/border_closing_coronavirus_14062020)" or "an A1 or A5 visa issued by Israel".

Note that even though you have no checked baggage:

- Since your two flight are booked separately, for Ryanair your final destination is Tel Aviv, so you need documentation to enter Israel, not just transit airside;
- For at least El Al flights departing from TLV you need to be present at the check-in desk at least one hour before departure, even if you check-in online (which these days is anyway often impossible), so again, you'll need to enter Israel.

It doesn't really change things in your case anyway since the prohibition is the same for entry and transit into Israel.

Note that even if you had a permit, you would need to undergo mandatory quarantine for 24 hours or until a negative test result, and leaving Israel before the end of the quarantine is not allowed.

Note that changes are planned for 14 September (Cyprus moves from orange to yellow list), [19 September](https://www.touristisrael.com/when-will-travel-to-israel-resume/31963/) (entry allowed for groups of 5 or more fully vaccinated), October (group tours for individual travelers) but as far as I can see no changes are planned for transit yet.

Also note that in addition to COVID-related restrictions, you may need a visa to enter Israel even for transit (TWOV doesn't apply here), depending on your citizenship.

Comment: Hello, as far as i know i meet the criteria to enter Israel so assume I will be able to get a letter. I wasn't aware there were countries where TWOV wasn't possible so that is very concerning

Comment: Luckily i do have connection protection so if i cannot make my second flight it is covered by the company i purchased both tickets with

Comment: I'm not sure what makes you think you meet the criteria? The list of reasons that allow you to get the authorisation letter is very limited (family members of Israel citizens, weddings, funerals, urgent life-saving medical procedures...). It does not include transit, and has lots of additional requirements (test on arrival, quarantine until the result of the test, getting an electronic bracelet, not being allowed to leave before the end of the quarantine, health insurance...). Unless the rules change by then, it is very unlikely you will get the letter or be allowed to board.

Comment: I seriously doubt "connection protection" will cover anything in this case. You are not likely to even board the first flight. I very strongly recommend you look into your options to rebook to a different itinerary, ideally as a single ticket.

Comment: I smell a certain rotten fruit here... If this was indeed purchased through Kiwi the OP is not really protected. Kiwi's promises are not really worth a lot. And Ryanair has decided to make life very hard for people who book through Kiwi.

Answer (score -1):

Just regarding transit, since it is a different PNR, you have to call the checking gate and pray that they will send someone to open the connections door, they really do not like, in Sep 2018, according to this, 142 did a connection in TLV!
More into here:
https://flying-out.com/2018/10/23/tlv-connection/

Comment: This seems to completely miss the point of the question and the existing answer which is about what happens now in 2021 with COVID-19 not what may have been possible in 2018.

Comment: But I said, *just regarding the transit*-the previous answer talked about covid so I have nothing to add there. If anything, transiting today is worse because of covid.