# European travelling to Israel - September 2021

Tags: europe, covid-19, israel

I am a Spanish citizen (with vaccines) planning to travel to Israel from the 24th of September to the 3rd of October 2021. My concerns are:

- The [Israeli Ministry of Health website](https://corona.health.gov.il/en/directives/air-travel-covid19-green/?tab=by-air) states that the only requirement is a PCR test done no more than 72 hours before departure. Are there any other Covid restrictions regarding traveling?
- How is the current Covid situation in Isreal are there any restrictions or limitations such as lockdowns?
- Are all regions in Israel safe to travel to? How is the current state of the conflict?

Thank you for taking your time, any other comment that you think is worth mentioning is well received.

Comment: Do you have Israeli citizenship or special permission to travel from their Ministry of Interior? Israel is still applying travel restrictions so if the answer is no you’re out of luck.

Comment: You missed the “foreign nationals” section on that page. Foreign nationals are not allowed into Israel except under a limited number of circumstances (basically, immediate family, weddings, funerals, urgent medical care…). There are plans to gradually relax restrictions, for groups first, then for individual tourists assigned to groups, but definitely no way to freely roam the country for now.

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168663/connecting-flight-in-tel-aviv/168664#168664 for details. The original question there is about transit, but the answer is basically the same.

Answer (score 3):

[These](https://www.gov.il/he/departments/news/border_closing_coronavirus_14062020) are the current entry restrictions to Israel in Hebrew, I couldn't find an English version.

1. If you are not an Israeli citizen or permanent resident, you can't enter without a valid visa or an entry permit. Entry permit may be issued to if you have close relatives in Israel.
2. There are no restrictions like lockdowns that should affect a tourist. However, every one entering must be in quarantine for two weeks, or one week with a negative PCR test and non Israeli citizens must have a valid COVID-19 health insurance. In addition many places are required to check for vaccination certificate

Comment: I think [this is the English version](https://www.gov.il/en/departments/news/border_closing_coronavirus_14062020) of the document you linked above.

Comment: "can't enter without a valid visa or an entry permit" is misleading - a valid visa issued before the pandemic is not necessarily enough.

Answer (score 2):

The answer keeps changing, and there are fine details.

Since the pandemic started, non-Israelis were generally denied entry to Israel, except with a special permit. A visa was not enough.

Starting 2021/11/01 this was relaxed, and vaccinated tourists were allowed in (under limitations).

Recently, due to the Omicron variant, this decision was temporarily reverted ([Hebrew source](https://www.ynet.co.il/news/article/bkmtqybfy#autoplay)). For 2 weeks starting 2021/11/28, foreigners are again not allowed to enter without a special permit.

[The official Ministry of Health page](https://corona.health.gov.il/en/directives/air-travel-covid19-green/?tab=by-air) doesn't seem to reflect this recent change.